# Show different geoms in a legend for a common aesthetic

Tags: r, ggplot2

This graph uses points, pointranges, and lines to plot different kinds of data. The data sources are distinguished by color.

Currently, the legend shows all the geoms at once.

I would like the legend to reflect *only the geom used with that color*. So:

- "acs 1-year" will only show a **pointrange**
- "admin v1" and "admin v2" will only show a **line**
- "decennial census" will only show a **point**

I want to keep all four legend entries in a single legend for the "colour" aesthetic.
[image]

Here is the replication data.

```
df <- structure(list(year = c(1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 
1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 
2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 
2019, 2020, 2021, 2022), admin1 = c(105939L, 105568L, 105207L, 
105252L, 104878L, 104498L, 103960L, 104071L, 103689L, 103474L, 
104039L, 104874L, 104949L, 105767L, 106559L, 107339L, 106348L, 
105580L, 104455L, 102815L, 101121L, 99244L, 96823L, 95091L, 94082L, 
92769L, 91811L, 91680L, 91350L, 82767L, 89030L, 89764L, 89942L
), admin2 = c(105944L, 105573L, 105209L, 105254L, 104880L, 104500L, 
103961L, 104072L, 103691L, 103475L, 104039L, 104874L, 104949L, 
105767L, 106559L, 107339L, 106348L, 106021L, 104874L, 103208L, 
101580L, 99732L, 97343L, 95648L, 94685L, 93390L, 92467L, 92375L, 
92137L, 92703L, 93417L, 94222L, 95200L), decennial_count = c(107682, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 105235, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 100296, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), acs1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 113122, 109275, 105005, 105918, 104330, 102660, 
98506, 95432, 97196, 97841, 94046, 93184, 92218, 96609, 92982, 
NA, 96044, NA), acs1_moe = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4433, 3735, 3484, 3227, 3379, 3527, 
3171, 3259, 3105, 3800, 3711, 3232, 3507, 3816, 3261, NA, 3817, 
NA)), row.names = c(NA, -33L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

And here is the minimal ggplot2 code.

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_line(aes(x = year, y = admin1, color = "admin v1")) +
  geom_line(aes(x = year, y = admin2, color = "admin v2")) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(x = year, y = acs1, ymin = (acs1 - acs1_moe),
                      ymax = (acs1 + acs1_moe), color = "acs 1-year")) +
  geom_point(aes(year, decennial_count, color = "decennial census"),
             size = 4, shape = "diamond")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the legend keys all grouped under the color aesthetic but different shapes for each one, you will need to override the guide aesthetics manually

```r
ggplot(df) +
  geom_line(aes(x = year, y = admin1, color = "admin v1")) +
  geom_line(aes(x = year, y = admin2, color = "admin v2")) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(x = year, y = acs1, ymin = (acs1 - acs1_moe),
                      ymax = (acs1 + acs1_moe), color = "acs 1-year"),
                  key_glyph = draw_key_blank) +
  geom_point(aes(year, decennial_count, color = "decennial census"),
             size = 4, shape = "diamond") +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = c(1, 1, 1, 0),
                                                   shape = c(16, NA, NA, 18),
                                                   size = c(3, 1, 1, 4))))
```

[image]